# How to get total non-Prime Factors of number with fast runtime?

Tags: c

I am learning C on a competitive programming website. The question is, Given a number, how many non-Prime Factors the number have? I can do it with my code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int totalNPF(int n){
    int totalFactor = 1, temp = 0, primeFactor = 0;
    for(int i=2; n!=1;){
        while(n % i == 0){
            n /= i;
            temp++;
        }
        if(temp != 0){
            totalFactor *= (temp+1);
            primeFactor ++;
        }

        i++;
        temp = 0;
    }

    return totalFactor-primeFactor;
}

int main(){
    int T, n;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d\n", totalNPF(n));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use the number theory concept, but it's still slow. It have a runtime above 1s. Does anyone know how to improve the speed so I can get the speed around 1s or below?

**NOTE: The constraints of the number is 2x10^6**

Comment: Is this considered helping with homework? Or can one answer this?

Comment: Solve first the math problem. Then program your solution.

Comment: I don't know other math trick to solve it anymore. That's why I asked here.

Comment: for 143, it have 2 prime factor(11 & 13). To get the non prime factor, just subtract total factor it have which is 4(exponent of 11+1(= 2) times exponent of 13+1(= 2)). So the total of non prime factor is 2. I have used that algorithm as you can see in my code(yeah maybe it's not clear). But, it's still slow.

Comment: You're calculating prime numbers over and over again ... `T` times. Calculate once, up to `2x10^3`

Comment: I don't get what you mean @pmg. How can I calculate the total of prime numbers once?

Comment: The [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) would work well here. It precomputes a table of primes (and thus composites) up to a certain upper bound. Instead of using an array of boolean flags for each number, use an array of numbers initialized to zero; increment by one for each factor found. Then just look up the value in the table for each user input.

Comment: calculate the primes themselves: `int primes[200] = {2, 3, 5}; primes[3] = 7; primes[4] = 11; ...` (maybe even write them literally in code). Then use them to factorize.

Comment: Make that [`primes[250]`](http://webprimes.com/?prime=1600) to go up to `1597`.

Comment: @pmg Best way to precalculate the primes is with the Sieve of Eratosthenes which, with a trivial modification, can also count the factors of the composites (just remember how many times each number has been marked as composite). So there is no reason not to do this in a single step and avoid factorization altogether.

Comment: @TypeIA I finally can calculate non prime factor for prime numbers only from sieve method itself, but still I don't know how to calculate non prime factor of composite numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The program can be made faster by changing `for(int i=2; n!=1;){` to `for(int i=2; i*i <= n;){`. This terminates the search for factors once `n` is less than the square of the current candidate factor. There can be no prime factors after this point, other than `n` itself, since if `j` were a prime factor greater than `i`, then `n/j` would be a factor less than `i`. But such a factor would have been extracted from `n` earlier in the loop.

Since this means the loop may exit with `n` being a prime factor, it is necessary to insert some code after the loop to test whether `n` is greater than 1 and, if so, adjust `totalFactor` and `primeFactor` accordingly.

The program can also be made faster by testing only prime numbers as candidate factors instead of testing every integer from 2 on. Note that, since the program is required to support numbers up to 2,000,000, and the new loop will stop at the square root of `n`, only primes up to 1,414 are needed. A list of such primes can easily be prepared in advance.